# OnBubbleEvent called twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm experiencing an issue whereby OnBubbleEvent is being called twice.  The code-behind for the user control that fires the initial RaiseBubbleEvent is as follows:

```
protected void CreateButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        RaiseBubbleEvent(this, new CreateButtonClickedEventArgs<DebtModel>
        {
            Model = ModelBinder.Bind<DebtModel>(this)
        });
    }
    catch (ModelBindingException e)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The OnBubbleEvent in the parent form:

```
protected override bool OnBubbleEvent(object source, EventArgs args)
{
    var arguments = args as CreateButtonClickedEventArgs<DebtModel>;

    if (arguments != null)
    {
        CreateDebt(arguments.Model);

        return true;
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException(
        "Parameter arguments cannot be cast to CreateButtonClickedEventArgs<DebtModel> or is null.");
}
```

Finally CreateDebt's relevant code:

```
public void CreateDebt(DebtModel debtModel)
{
    ...

    Response.RedirectWithoutException(
        "~/foo/bar/DebtAmendForm.aspx?session={0}&debt={1}",
            Request.Parameter<string>("session"), debtModel.Id);
}
```

I've placed a breakpoint on the RaiseBubbleEvent call and it is only being hit the once.  There are no other user controls on the form that call RaiseBubbleEvent.  I'm totally stuck on this one and need some help!

Thank you.

Comment: Fixed by checking the source of the event.  I'm simply doing an if (source is Button).  Can anyone explain this?  Surely a button within a user control within a form should still only result in one bubbled event?

Comment: ACTUALLY!!!  if (source is Button) is the second bubbled event so my DebtModel is null.  Instead it should be if (source is DebtCreateControl).